# Live reloading not working after Ctrl + S in GULP

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I do not know why those tasks for live reloading just disappear after the last Ionic Update I did. Now I am trying to fix this issue but still wondering why is not working. I am following [this guide here](http://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp) and still can not see what is the error I have.

See some part of my `gulpfile.js`

```
var paths = {
  sass: ['/scss/**/*.scss'],
  js: ['www/js/*.js', 'www/js/**/*.js', '!www/js/lib.min.js', '!www/js/code.min.js']
};

gulp.task('compress-lib', function() {
  gulp.src([
    './www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js'
  ])
    .pipe(concat('lib.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js'))
});

gulp.task('compress-js', function() {
  gulp.src([
    './www/js/app.js',
    './www/js/lines/controller.js',
    './www/js/lines/service.js'
  ])
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(concat('code.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js'))
});

// JSHint task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.js)
      .pipe(jscs())
      .pipe(jshint())
      .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({onError: function(e) { console.log(e); } }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions', 'Chrome', 'ios_saf','Android'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.js, ['lint', 'compress-js']);
});
```

every time I do `ctrl + s` on a file, in this case `www/js/lines/controller.js`,  on the console you can see something like:

```
[14:41:11] Starting 'lint'...
[14:41:11] Finished 'lint' after 17 ms
[14:41:11] Starting 'compress-js'...
[14:41:11] Finished 'compress-js' after 5.31 ms
JS changed:   www/js/lines/controller.js
JS changed:   www/js/code.min.js
```

which means that there are some tasks working properly, but if I want to see those changes on the view, I have to go to the console and type `gulp`, do you have an idea why the app is not just reloading after `ctrl + s` ?

**UPDATE**

This is what I am trying to implement (you can see it on the link I pasted above):

"The watch task is used to run tasks as we make changes to our files. As you write code and modify your files, the gulp.watch() method will listen for changes and automatically run our tasks again so we don't have to continuously jump back to our command-line and run the gulp command each time"

Comment: I fail to see any livereload related things in your gulpfile.

Comment: @Heikki if you use this ```gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.js, ['lint', 'compress-js']);
});``` its suppose to do a reload of your views once you do ctrl + s on your files.

Comment: No, it watches the files and runs specified tasks.

Comment: @Heikki look: The watch task is used to run tasks as we make changes to our files. As you write code and modify your files, the gulp.watch() method will listen for changes and automatically run our tasks again so we don't have to continuously jump back to our command-line and run the gulp command each time.

Comment: ok, what I need to do to use live reload ? can you show me or give me an example base on my code. @Heikki

Comment: There is **no livereload** related things in your (partial?) gulpfile.

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/server-with-livereload-and-css-injection.md

Comment: @Heikki nope, that's all I have in my gulpfile. I just saw this https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload but then, I do not have an idea why before my app was reloading every time a saved a change on a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is going around the problem but use live-server instead of live reload and see if that works. Because I have had a lot of problems with live-reload in the past too.

```
npm install live-server
```

then:

```
live-server
```

NOTE: Make sure you are in the directory of your project when typing the command above.